# My backbone.js view doesn't render anything

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, backbone.js

I just get a blank screen. What am I doing wrong?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/template" id="view-navigation-bar-template">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="button" value="Day" /></li>
            <li ><input type="button" value="Week" /></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="Month" /></li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <script src="common.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="view-navigation-bar" class="button-list">
        <!-- Insert view-navigation-bar_template here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**common.js**

```
ViewNavigationBarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template( $("#view-navigation-bar-template").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html( template );

        return this;
    }
});

viewNavigationBarView = new ViewNavigationBarView({ el: $("#view-navigation-bar") });
```

Comment: ...You're not even waiting for the document ready event?

Comment: Ah, so it's a concurrency issue?

Comment: maybe. I'm not familiar with the view system of Backbone, but... just wrap the lot into a `$(document).ready(function() { })` just to see if that is the likely problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the OP's question relied in the absence of a document.ready listener. Backbone views do not, by themselves, wait for the DOM to be available. Inserting immediately therefore did not do anything.

Quick fix: wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { });`